# Equation system with $f_1, f_2, e_1$ and $e_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I get the $f_1$ and $f_2$ alone on the left side of the equal

$$-\frac12f_1-f_2=e_1$$
$$\frac12f_2-f_1=e_2$$

my answer is

$$f_1=e_1+\frac12e_2$$
$$f_2=e_2+\frac12e_1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}\text{I}\;\;&-\frac12f1-f2&=e1\\\text{II}\;\;&
\;\;\;\frac12f2-f1&=e2\end{align*}$$

So now we sum

$$\text{I$\;+\;2\;$II}=-\frac52f_1=e_1+2e_2\implies f_1=-\frac{2e_1+4e_2}5$$

and now just substitute this in any of the two equations I, II above and get the value for $\,f_2\,$ .

Your solution is wrong but I can't tell where and how since you didn't write your work.